# PHP, session not storing above a certain number of DB records

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I just found myself in a strange situation.

I have 3 servers:

**Server H:**

- DB
- App (v.3.222)

**Server D:**

- DB
- App (v.3.23)

**Local Server:**

- DB
- App (v.3.23)

The App is made with Codeigniter and it reads from the DB a table containing a number of shops, when I click one of them I load and store some of the data from the DB to a Session, then I route to a page to display other info as well as Session infos.

When the DB contains 13 shops there is no problem. While if I add a shop from the DB (now containing 14 shops) the PHP Session stops to get stored and I get errors. Is like the session is empty, any info in the session either get loaded and deleted, or not loaded at all.

The strange thing is that the problem is present on `Server H` and `Server D`, but not in local. If I run the local server and load the `Server H DB` works fine, same if I load the `Server D DB` in local. So the problem is not the DB. Changing the App version also does the same.

***EDIT***

The shop loaded is an array containing a few data:

```
'username' => $this->input->post('user'), //64
'is_logged_in' => TRUE, //Bool
'nome' => $this->login_model->nome, //128
'usrclass' => $this->login_model->usrclass, //32
'defaultlevel' => $this->login_model->defaultlevel, //32
'usremail' => $this->login_model->usremail, //64
'usershop' => $this->login_model->usershop, //INT
```

Too few to think is a memory problem.

The only thing left is the Configuration of the 2 servers, but what?

Is there a php.ini problem? How do I find out?

***EDIT 2***

I found out it is a memory issue. The 'usershop' contains an array, if it is 13 record it works fine, if bigger the following variables are not stored into the memory.

I looked around and I found out there is no limit o a php session (memory/size-wise), so how is this possible?

Comment: About what amount of data are we talking? Is a shop basically a string? Or do you store tons of data?

Comment: I edited the post, the data are very few as you can see.

Comment: The fact that it is working with 13 but not with 14 shops makes me imagine only two possible options: Either a  memory problem or the 14th shop you entered is the problem. Does the problem also occur when removing one shop and adding the new one?

Comment: Dear Frank, yes does the same thing... I also thought about memory issues but looking around I see there is no PHP limit to a session memory. I found out IT IS a memory issue (an array contains 14 records stops other variables to be written onto the same session). Now how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a memory issue/file size/column size combination issue.

Your session, depending on how you are storing it, is limited either to the file size (if saving to file) which is typically 128MB or to the column size if storing to db.

Also check your memory limit in php.ini as this may also have an effect.